# Is there a personal cloud solution that keep versions for documents?

Tags: backup, nas, cloud, personal-data

Today I have lost a file which I've worked on for the last day & half by a mistake.

As result, I'm looking to buy a personal cloud solution which will automatically backup my files while I save them on the local machine and will allow me to return for a specific version (version tree).

Is there something like this? I've read about NAS but I'm not sure if that's what I need.

I'll appreciate your help.

Answer (score 14):

Unbeknownst to many people, but knowst to us (Spaceballs movie reference), Dropbox does keep [file versions](https://www.dropbox.com/help/11).

"Dropbox is like a time machine. It keeps snapshots of every change in your Dropbox folder over the last 30 days (or longer with the [Packrat](https://www.dropbox.com/help/113) feature). So even if you saved a bad change, or if the file has been damaged or deleted, you can restore the file to an older version with only a few clicks."

Answer (score 7):

The free and open-source [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.com/) allows this. You can set it up on your personal server, or use one of the [providers](https://owncloud.org/providers/). Also, if it's on your own server, it's unlimited storage and guaranteed NSA-free (and [Condoleezza Rice–free](http://www.drop-dropbox.com/)).

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/) is a great free product with up to 15GB Free storage, that keeps your previous versions.

It's super handy if you already have a Microsoft email account, and you can install a client locally that will sync your changes online. Easily accessible from anywhere!

Good luck :)

Comment: This is only true for Office filetypes - other types do not have their version history maintained.